# GraphQL query for Sorare data

Tags: python, graphql

I am trying to fetch data from sorare using their GraphQL API.  I have managed to find the pattern to make a query as follows:

```
import requests

# Define the GraphQL query
query = """
{
  player(slug: "nico-schlotterbeck") {
    firstName
    lastName
    position
    cardPositions
    id
    slug
    activeClub {
      name
    }
    age
    so5Scores(last: 5) {
      score
    }
  }
}
"""

# Define the Sorare GraphQL API URL
api_url = "https://api.sorare.com/graphql"

# Make a POST request to the Sorare GraphQL API
response = requests.post(api_url, json={"query": query})

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the JSON response
    data = response.json()
    
    # Extract player information
    player_data = data["data"]["player"]
    
    # Print the player information
    print("Player Name:", player_data["firstName"], player_data["lastName"])
    print("Position:", player_data["position"])
    print("Card Positions:", player_data["cardPositions"])
    print("ID:", player_data["id"])
    print("Slug:", player_data["slug"])
    print("Active Club:", player_data["activeClub"]["name"])
    print("Age:", player_data["age"])
    
    print("Last 5 SO5 Scores:")
    for score_data in player_data["so5Scores"]:
        print("  - Score:", score_data["score"])
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve data. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

The problem is, I want to fetch more information most importantly player's **current price or market value**. Can anyone please suggest what should be the query for that?

I searched a lot but could not find any suitable source for this.
I tried using `currentPrice` in the query but it returns error.

Answer (score 0):

[Sorare](https://github.com/sorare/api/tree/master) has documented its schema via a [graphiql playground](https://api.sorare.com/federation/graphql/playground) - I suggest you use that to explore the schema. It has a search function.

The `player` type doesn't have a `price` or `value` field directly but the `DraftablePlayer` and `SwappablePlayer` types each have a `value` field.